# Find the highest value in an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array made of several hashes. I would like to find the highest value for a specific key/value and print the name value for that hash. For example, I have a "student" array of hashes containing information to each student. I would like to find which student had the highest test score and print their name out. For the array below, "Kate Saunders" has the highest test score, so I would like to print out her name.

Any help or pointers were to start on this would be greatly appreciated. I have a hacky work around right now, but I know there's a better way. I'm new to Ruby and loving it, but stumped on this one. Thanks so much!!!

```
students = [
    {
        name: "Mary Jones",
        test_score: 80,
        sport: "soccer"
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Kelly",
        test_score: 95,
        sport: "basketball"
    }.
    {
        name: "Kate Saunders",
        test_score: 99,
        sport: "hockey"
    },
    {
        name: "Pete Dunst",
        test_score: 88,
        sport: "football"
    }
]
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far?
2. What's the hacky way you already have? Add code of the same.

Comment: My hacky way is pushing the test scores into a separate array and getting the index of the highest and comparing that to the hash index in the students array. It's pretty ugly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `max_by`method

```
students = [ { name: "Mary Jones", test_score: 80, sport: "soccer" }, { name: "Bob Kelly", test_score: 95, sport: "basketball" }, { name: "Kate Saunders", test_score: 99, sport: "hockey" }, { name: "Pete Dunst", test_score: 88, sport: "football" } ]

students.max_by{|k| k[:test_score] }
#=> {:name=>"Kate Saunders", :test_score=>99, :sport=>"hockey"}

students.max_by{|k| k[:test_score] }[:name]
#=> "Kate Saunders"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
students = [ { name: "Mary Jones", test_score: 80, sport: "soccer" },
             { name: "Bob Kelly", test_score: 95, sport: "basketball" },
             { name: "Kate Saunders", test_score: 99, sport: "hockey" },
             { name: "Pete Dunst", test_score: 88, sport: "football" },
             { name: "Ima Hogg", test_score: 99, sport: "darts" }
           ]
```

Determine the highest score ala @Bartek.

```
max_score = students.max_by { |h| h[:test_score] }[:test_score]
  #=> 99
```

Then determine which student(s) had that score.

```
star_students = students.select { |h| h[:test_score] == max_score }.
                         map { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> ["Kate Saunders", "Ima Hogg"] 

puts star_students
  # Kate Saunders
  # Ima Hogg
```

Ima's father was [James ("Big Jim") Hogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Hogg), governor of Texas between 1891 and 1895. That Ima had a sister named "Ura" (which I thought was fact) turns out to be urban legend.

Comment: Thanks Cary! Just saw your comment above. Sorry! Still learning the etiquette of how to use Stack Overflow. So, I jumped at the first answer that worked - beginner's mistake. Thanks for your solution. It's a nice alternative and gets the job done!